# Recycler view. Animate each item on create

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to animate each view with delay. Curently all item are animated together on create. and only when i scroll the new added items are animated so i want to animate the initilly created items in the recycler view this is my code in my recycler view adapter

```
 private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position)
    {
        // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
        if (position > lastPosition)
        {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_left);
            animation.setDuration(1000);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }

 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/gothamlight.ttf");
        NavigationData navigationData = arrayList.get(position);
        holder.NavigationImage.setImageResource(navigationData.getImg_res());
        holder.NavigationTitle.setText(navigationData.getNavigationTitle());
        holder.NavigationTitle.setTypeface(tf);
        setAnimation(holder.Container, position);

    }
```

Comment: The problem is you're starting the animation inside the onBindViewHolder which states: "/**
         * Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position. This method
         * should update the contents of the {@link ViewHolder#itemView} to reflect the item at
         * the given position." 
So, whenever a item is displayed on the screen, it start the animation.

Answer (score 0):

try increasing the duration in your animation file i.e. *slide_left* in your case.

**slide_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutition i found is declare an int of duration with the default animation duration and inside set animation i have duration = duration + 300. And it works great.